# Android - How to hide soft keyboard from dialog with multiple EditTexts when clicking outside any one of them?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog

I was wondering, in a Dialog with multiple EditTexts, is there any way to hide the soft keyboard if the user clicks outside any one of them?  This dialog has a LOT of EditTexts, and I would like an easy way for the user to hide the soft keyboard.

Since the EditTexts are in the form of a table, I prefer not to use `imeOptions="actionDone"` for every single EditText, since there are times when the user needs to enter data in an entire column.  However, if the user only needs to enter partial data, I would like it where the user can click outside of any EditText and hide the soft keyboard.

I have looked up several solutions here, but none of them seem to work for my scenario.  They only seem to work in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting `OnTouchListener` for `ViewGroup` parent of all these `EditText`s? and when `MotionEvent` is not consumed by any of them (method returns `true`/`false`) then run your method `hideKeyboard();`? (some examples [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard))

also you wrote

> and I would like an easy way for the user to hide the soft keyboard.

isn't `Back` physical/on-screen button intended to do that? Always accessible in same place on the front of device, the easiest way... (for usual devices, maybe you have some custom...) But I admit that touching outside any `EditText` closing keyboard is UX-friendly

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like setting the root and child container views to `clickable`, `focusable`, and `focusableInTouchMode` to `true` did the trick, along with the following code:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public void setupDialog(View view) {
    // Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupDialog(innerView);
        }
    }
}
```

Where you pass in the id of the root view of the dialog.

Answer (score -1):

No user clicks outside of a EditText to escape from it. You should better use "actionGo" or "actionDone" for your input fields.

But if you really-really need it, I recommend using **onFocusChangeListener**. 
Use this code to hide keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Then check you have this for your EditText:

```
android:clickable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```